# nypd motor vehicle collisions api query

Tags: socrata, soda

I am trying to query the nypd collisions API.
The following url is a successful query
"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/qiz3-axqb.geojson?$where=within_circle(location,%2040.73214,%20-73.99860000000001,%20100)&number_of_persons_injured=1"
But i cannot seem to query the same with 'number_of_persons_injured > 0'
I get an error for that query when trying to combine it with 'within_circle'
It would be extra help if you could tell me how to query 'within_circle()AND(number_of_persons_injured > 0ORnumber_of_persons_killed > 0)'
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this more what you're thinking?

```
GET https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/qiz3-axqb.geojson?$where=within_circle(location,%2040.73214,%20-73.99860000000001,%20100)%20AND%20(number_of_persons_injured%20%3E%200%20OR%20number_of_persons_killed%20%3E%200)
```

All I did was drop the `number_of_persons_injured=1` since that's duplicated in the `$where`, and I added spaces around your `AND`s and `OR`.